# How do I pass an event as a callback method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i'm having trouble solving an issue i'm facing regarding jQuery.

Some Background:
I'm working on a project where I take Json files that represent questions. A simplified version of the Json is as follows:

```
{
"questionOne": {
    "id": "questionOne",

    "options": {
        "0": "First option",
        "1": "Second option"
    },
    "answers": {
        "0": "Answer for first option",
        "1": "Answer for second option"
    },

    "alerts": {
        "0": "danger",
        "1": "success"
    },
    "type": "select",
    "correctAnswer": 2
},

"questionTwo": {
    "id": "questionTwo",

    "options": {
        "0": "First option",
        "1": "Second option"
    },
    "answers": {
        "0": "Answer for first option",
        "1": "Answer for second option"
    },

    "alerts": {
        "0": "danger",
        "1": "success"
    },
    "type": "checkBox",
    "correctAnswer": [2, 3]
}
```

Now, in a separate javascript file i'm calling the Json using the `$.getJSON` method like this (`#questionOne` is an html id where I want the Json content to be inserted, `"millionaire"` is the name of the Json file):

```
$('#questionOne').ready(function () {
        GetQuestionFromJson("millionaire", "questionOne");
        alert("questions loaded");
    });
```

The `"GetQuestionFromJson"` successfully loads the correct question into the `#questionOne` div and creates a button with the id "`questionOneButton"` in a separate div right after the question div. up to here everything works fine.

I can't seem to get the `"$('#questionOneButton').click"` event to work:

```
//end of "questionOneReady" function
$('#questionOneButton').click(function () {
            alert("button clicked");
        });
```

I have tried different solutions in order to get this working but with no solution yet.
I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the functions being called in an asynchronous way and that `"$('#questionOneButton').click"` is getting created before  `$('#questionOne').ready` has a chance to create the div with the `'#questionOneButton'` id.

Questions:

1. Am I correct?
2. How can I overcome this?

It's important to me to keep the files separated. Is this possible? what are my options?

Comment: What does `GetQuestionFromJson` do? A minor side node: a function that is called `getSomething()` that doesn't have a return value is very strange.

Comment: Try to move $('#questionOneButton').click on ready function of questionOne OR try with $('#questionOneButton').live("click", function( e ) {} );

Comment: @Max `live()` has been deprecated for years, and was completely removed several major versions ago

Comment: @Halcyon Thanks for the note, I will  give it a proper name or return a value to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the order in which you are adding content to the site and setting the event handler. You can only set an event handler to an existing element.

The best way to deal with such a setup, is to bind the handler to the document element and only react if the target matches. In jQuery this looks as the following example:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '#questionOneButton', function () {
    alert( "button clicked" );
} );
```

This way the event handler already exists and you can add the target element later.

See http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events for an extended description.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! This was the solution to my problem!

Comment: @Raskanskyz Then just decide for one of the matching answers and mark it as accepted answer. This would help following users a lot.

Comment: unfortunately I can't remove my vote of the later answer because it is locked. But I will take this in mind for future cases

Comment: @Raskanskyz I'm no talking about votes, but about accepting answers – that littel checkmark below the voting arrows…

Comment: thank u for the heads up! and again thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Define your event once elements are created in the success of the $.getJSON.

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
  //do stuff with data
  //create html elements
  //append onclick event
});
```

This answer assumes you're using jquery 1.5 otherwise i'll suggest that you read further [the doc for $.getJSON.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. Unfortunately, This solution is something I was trying to avoid because the elements are created in a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

When the elements don't exist at the time you try to bind event handlers you can use `event delegation` and bind to a permanent asset that will always exist.

```
$(document).on('click', '#questionOneButton',function () {
     alert("button clicked");
});
```

Otherwise bind the event handlers to the elements once they are inserted in DOM in your ajax callback

Comment: read up on event delegation , lots written aboout how it works

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation of your scenario,

It seems questionOneButton is created after the $.getJSON is called, which constructs the required UI.

Please attach the click handler after $.getJSON has completed. This will ensure the event handler is attached after the element is available in DOM.

```
$.getJSON("url",function(data)
 {
     //attach click handler here
 })
```

Please refer
[jQuery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Answer (score 0):

Your diagnosis sounds likely.

If you can't do something like this

```
$('#questionOne').ready(function () {
    GetQuestionFromJson("millionaire", "questionOne");
    alert("questions loaded");

    $('#questionOneButton').click(function () {
        alert("button clicked");
    });

});
```

You could try triggering a custom event toward the end of your callback to $('#questionOne').ready, and listening for that event as the cue to attach the event handler to the button.

```
$('#questionOne').ready(function () {
    GetQuestionFromJson("millionaire", "questionOne");
    alert("questions loaded");

    $(document).trigger('my.event');

});

$(document).on('my.event',function(event){
    $('#questionOneButton').click(function () {
        alert("button clicked");
    });
});
```